# rxjs jest Mocking object in stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, jestjs

Hi I try to test this code

```
import { Observable, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
function getJavaRequest<T>(globals: any): (name: string) => Observable<T> {
return (name: string) => Observable
    .create((observer: Subscriber<T>) => {
        globals[name] = (event: T) => observer.next(event);
    });
    };
```

I am using jest framework. And I want to create mock object in jest and  check that function create stream and add someting to stream 
And I have something like this

```
import {getJavaRequest } from './JcefStreams';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';
test('It should return mocked object from stream', () => {
const testObject = jest.mock();
let test;
getJavaRequest(testObject).subscribe(e: any => e == test);

expect(test).toBe(global);
});
```

But it not working correctly

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a mocked observable.

For example:

```
//...
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

class RequestServiceMock {
  get = jest.fn();
}

describe('', () => {
  it('', () => {
    const requestService = RequestService as RequestServiceMock;
    requestService.get.mockReturnValue(of([]));

    requestService.get().subscribe(_ => expect(_).toBeTruthy())
  });
});
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response but in your solution, I will not check my getJavaRequest function I just mock all functionality. I have to mock global object and check the content of it after I execution my function

Answer (score 1):

Sollution based on https://blog.jiayihu.net/testing-observables-in-rxjs6/

```js
describe('Check that getJavaRequest create observable with event', () => {
  let scheduler: TestScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    scheduler = new TestScheduler(assertDeepEqual);
  });

  test('', () => {
    let testObject: {[name: string]: ((event: string) => void)} = {};

    const subscriber = jest.fn();
      const stremUnderTests = getJavaRequest<string>(testObject)('testStream').subscribe(subscriber);
    testObject.testStream('a');
    testObject.testStream('b');
    expect(subscriber).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a')
    expect(subscriber).toHaveBeenCalledWith('b')
    expect(subscriber).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)
  });
});
```